# SSL Certificate error when trying to download the Cybersource Magento Plugin

Tags: magento2, composer, ssl, magento2.4.1, cybersource

I'm trying to install the Cybersource package for Magento. I'm new to Magento, I had a pretty hard time installing Magento itself, but I got there. Now, I'm stuck installing this cybersource module.
I'm following this installion guide [Magento Cybersource Installation Guide](https://marketplace.magento.com/media/catalog/product/cybersource-global-payment-management-3-3-1-ce/installation_guides.pdf) to install the extension, for some reason, I get this error:
`curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/cybersource/global-payment-management.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`.
I tried doing these as suggested by some people, but it doesn't seem to work:

1. Download and place the `cacert.pem` in the PHP root/SSL directory and mention the path ibn `php.ini`.
2. Download the server certificate from `https://repo.packagist.org/p2/cybersource/global-payment-management.json` and add it to the `curl-ca-bundle` certificate.

As mentioned in the installation guide I've created my auth.json file in the project root directory and verified the public and private keys. I'm not sure what else is missing. Would really appreciate any help. Btw, I'm running Magento 2.4 on XAMPP.

Here's the error log:

````
The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "magento/composer-root-update-plugin" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded (curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
https://repo.magento.com could not be fully loaded (curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/cybersource/global-payment-management.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate```

**EDIT: As requested here's the diagnose log **
 
```Checking composer.json: WARNING
The version field is present, it is recommended to leave it out if the package is published on Packagist.
Defining autoload.psr-0 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance
require.magento/product-community-edition : exact version constraints (2.4.1) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://api.github.com/rate_limit: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Checking disk free space: OK
Checking pubkeys:
Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642
Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952
OK
Checking composer version: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] curl error 60 while downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
Composer version: 2.0.9
PHP version: 7.4.6
PHP binary path: C:\xampp\php\php.exe
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020
cURL version: 7.69.1 libz 1.2.11 ssl OpenSSL/1.1.1g
zip: extension present, unzip not available```
````

Comment: Could you share the result for `composer diagnose` command. You can try `composer config -- disable-tls true
composer config  secure-http false` for a temporary fix.

Comment: Hi, I've added the diagnose log as an edit in my question. Looks like it's not able it's not able to download others too.

Comment: Hi @Ani do you got any solution for the above issue. I am also facing the same